# What wheelset comes on this Trek?

Tags: wheels

Apologies if this is the wrong type of question to ask here, but I was just wondering if anyone knows what particular wheel set comes with [this Trek 1.5 2013 bike](http://www.evanscycles.com/products/trek/15-t-h2-2013-road-bike-ec040344). I'm pretty sure this is the one I currently own, but other than the fact they are Bontrager I can't figure out what specific ones they are. I recently was hit by a car on my bike and (thankfully) the only damage is to the front wheelset, so I was looking to find out the weight so that I can replace them appropriately.

Comment: Why do you care about the weight? Just find something at a reasonable price and then get it put on. Also, make sure there is no other significant damage (e.g. fork, since its carbon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Trek's website](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/2013/archive/trek/2013_1_5_h2_compact/#/us/en/archive-model/details?url=us/en/bikes/2013/archive/trek/2013_1_5_h2_compact) :

> Wheels: Alloy hubs w/Bontrager Approved alloy rims

And according to [Bikeradar's website](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/bikes/road/product/review-trek-bikes-1-5-12-44273/) :

> Front Wheel Weight: 1370g
>
> Rear Wheel Weight: 1970g

I fear that you won't be able to replace the wheel with exactly the same thing since they seem to be generic wheels built for this bike. You can try the dealer you bought them from, they might have a replacement available or you can look for a different set elsewhere. In that price category you might have to buy a set (front+rear wheel) thought, but at least that means they will match.

Comment: Oh no, I'm going to replace the set. I wanted to know the weight for an indication of the price, this seems really heavy for a wheelset? (Admittedly I don't know much about bikes though)

Comment: Yes they are "heavy". If you look at Campagnolo "low to middle of the pack" wheelset the Zonda (~400$ online), front is 680g and back is 890g, for a total of 1570g for both. Yours are more than twice as heavy, but it's to be expected from  cheaper wheelset. The less expensive Scirocco (~250$ online) is still much lighter than yours at 1750g for both.

Comment: Rethinking of those number, Bikeradar might include the tire and tube in the wheel weight, while I listed only the wheels weight (rim, hub spokes). But I don't think you have a 1kg tire on those anyways ;)

Comment: The only way the numbers could make sense would be if someone confused lbs and kilograms at some point. But that would be on the light side for this price point with rear at 893g and front 621g... I'd assume the numbers are just plain wrong and get entry level wheels from one of the big brands.

Comment: Get a mid-range set of front & rear wheel and you have a spare rear wheel with your old one. Put on a different cassette and you can nicely switch between gearings.

Answer (score 2):

According to my kitchen scales a Bontrager TREK 1.5c wheel (2015) weighs:

- Rear     1275g   with skewer, no cassette,no tyre or tube
- Front    925g    with skewer, no tyre or tube
- BOTH are 2200g.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly generic, machine built wheelset with Bontrager branding. They're almost certainly OEM which means you won't be able to by a replacement set. Most likely Alex or similar rims. As you noticed, they're not the lightest wheels out there. A set such as this would typically retail for well under $300. The Shimano R501 or Mavic Aksium One are both good replacement wheels to look at in this price range. Either would be a nice upgrade without breaking the bank. There are some fantastic deals to be had on wheels these days.